# Charge Injection in Charge Pumps

Tags: analog, circuit-design, filter, pll, charge-pump

let's consider the following charge pump, which is used a lot in some PLL circuits ([reference](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/1/1130.html)):

[image]

Let's focus on the left part of the circuit (until the Loop Filter Network): its aim is simply that of generating a pulse current which charges the Loop filter when UP is ON, and which discharges the Loop filter when Down is ON. This can be also done by using only two switches, but in this way 4 switches are used in order to compensate the charge injection problem, which is due to the gate - drain parasitic capacitance of each MOS switch.

This explanation is that I have read on my notes, in which there is also this scheme:

[image]

But I do not understand what exactly this charge injection problem is, and how the additional presence of two more transistors may reduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charge injection may or may not be a problem, depending on the performance required of the PLL.

Using two devices switching in antiphase, and making the assumption that an on-going device generates the opposite charge injection to an off-going device, gives you a first order cancellation of the injection current.

Uncancelled charge injection can be regarded as a frequency dependent error current. Where a PLL is used in a fixed frequency synthesiser, it can usually be ignored, as it results in a fixed offset. In a demodulator, the frequency dependent offset may simply result in an effective gain change, which is not usually a problem.

If the charge injection is temperature dependent or power supply voltage dependent, then it can give rise to more temperature drift or sensitivity to power rail fluctuations than you can tolerate.

In a fractional-N synthesiser, it's not usually tolerable, as what was frequency dependent in a fixed synthesiser is now data dependent, and different count sequences that should have the same weight now end up with different weights, causing non-linearity and down-mixing of the high frequency variations into the baseband. In fact, fracN synthesisers tend not to use charge pumps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But from a circuital point of view, which is the cause of that charge injection? For instance, in the last picture, when M4 is ON, is M2 which provokes charge injection?

Comment: when M4 transitions between on and off, and vice versa, it injects charge into all of its connections, due to stray capacitance and sharp control edges. The same goes for M2. As the control edges usually have a large swing and stray Cs are small, you can regard it as a high impedance current source, or charge source at each switching event.